# Nullable type not being applied when exporting

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a hard time understanding why it wont apply my nullable type

Heres an example

```
interface Book {
  name: string;
  author: string;
  reference: string;
  category: string;
}

async function handleFetch<T>(endpoint: string, params: object): Promise<T | null> {
  const querystring = Object.entries(params)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
    .join('&');

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/${endpoint}?${querystring}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
      return data[0] || null;
    }

    return null;
  } catch {
    throw new Error('Internal error');
  }
}

export default {
  getBook: (reference: string) => {
    return handleFetch<Book>('books', { reference });
  },
};
```

I can see that the method returns a nullable type [image]

but when exporing it isn't nullable anymore
[image]

I feel like I am missing something but have never encountered that before

thank you

Comment: Hi, indeed look strange!
should the getBook function definition have async / await ?
I wander if "somehow" if you pass the string in getBook then the compiler detect that handleFetch will never return null.

Comment: Yes `getBook` is async/await since `handleFetch` is itself, all it does is pass a custom object... I have `handleFetch` as a generic method for tens of other methods like `getBook` so passing an object is essential, not just a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only cause of this I can think of would be that [the `strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) is off. This is also included by [the `"strict"` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict)

Try adding:

```
"strict": true,
```

Or:

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
```

to your `tsconfig.json` file under the `"compilerOptions"` section.

In strict mode, your code seems to work fine. See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-wright-u95p3?file=/src/index.ts).

Comment: I had strict already set to true but I added strictNullChecks and it did not change anything. 

I just discovered that line `"include": ["src/**/*.ts"]` in tsconfig was messing around with types, when moving the file from bottom screenshot to `src` folder it works fine ... See [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-shamir-m41pc?file=/index.ts)

Comment: Since this will be a npm library should I keep include/exclude in tsconfig ?

Comment: It's hard to answer that without understanding your project structure. But yes, in general, `tsconfig.json` needs to be configured to include all typescript files in the project. And putting those in `/src` is a good and common convention. This lets your transpile them to `/dist` and keeps the typescript files separate from the transpiled javascript.